# SeekBar won't run when media player are playing on xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The SeekBar widget is an interactive slider that allows the user to select one value from a range of values. As the user moves the slider left or right, the value of the SeekBar will change

```cs
public int getProgressPercentage(int currentDuration, int totalDuration)
{
    int percentage;

    int currentSeconds = (int)(currentDuration / 1000);
    int totalSeconds = (int)(totalDuration / 1000);

    //calculating percentage

    percentage = (((int)currentSeconds) / totalSeconds) * 100;

    return percentage;
}
```

```cs
public void UpdatedTimerTask()
{
    //Displaying time
    //txtCurrentTimer.Text = utils.miliSecondsTotimer (player.CurrentPosition);
    //txtTotalTimer.Text = utils.miliSecondsTotimer (player.Duration);

    //Updating progress bar(seekbar)
    int progress=(int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(player.CurrentPosition,player.Duration));
    seekBar.Progress = progress;
}

void SeekBar_ProgressChanged (object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdatedTimerTask ();
}

public void StartMedia(string url_string)
{

    player = new MediaPlayer ();
    seekBar.Progress = 0;
    seekBar.Max = 100;
    player.Reset ();
    player.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
    player.SetDataSource(url_string);
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start ();
    imgPlayorPause.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_pause_black_36dp);
    UpdatedTimerTask ();
}
```

`seekBar.SetOnSeekBarChangeListener (this);` has some invalid argument.

SeekBar won't run when media player are playing.

Comment: Please use c# syntax highlighting instead of snippets with HTML highlighting in your future questions. It is not HTML. See what I have changed in the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

### SetOnSeekBarChangeListener()

If you want to use `SetOnSeekBarChangeListener` you have to implement `IOnSeekBarChangeListener` in the class of `this` (usually your activity. The **disadvantage** of this is, that you can only have one event listener.

```cs
[Activity]
public class MyActivity : Activity, SeekBar.IOnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // ...
        seekbar.SetOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void OnProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, bool fromUser)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    public void OnStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }

    public void OnStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }
}
```

### ProgressChanged Event

Xamarin maps Java methods that are called like `SetXyzListener` to the event called `Xyz`.
If you want to use `ProgressChanged` you have to register your handler with `seekbar.ProgressChanged += SeekbarOnProgressChanged`. The **disadvantage** of this is, that you have to ensure to remove the handler with `seekbar.ProgressChanged -= SeekbarOnProgressChanged` when you do not need the event anymore. You should do this in the counterpart of the lifecycle method where you have added the handler. In the following example I used `OnResume` and `OnPause`.

```cs
[Activity]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // ...
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        seekbar.ProgressChanged += SeekbarOnProgressChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        seekbar.ProgressChanged -= SeekbarOnProgressChanged;
        base.OnPause();
    }

    private void SeekbarOnProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs progressChangedEventArgs)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```